# How to properly "extend" a Record<>?

Tags: typescript

```
type SingleValue =  string | number | bigint | boolean | null 
type Value = SingleValue | SingleValue[]


function insert<T extends Record<string,Value>>(x: T) {

}

interface User {
  id: number
  name: string
}

insert<User>({  // <-- error
  id: 1,
  name: 'mpen',
})
```

https://go.mpen.ca/5reow

This gives an error:

> Type 'User' does not satisfy the constraint 'Record<string, Value>'.
> Index signature is missing in type 'User'.(2344)

I understand that `User` is missing an index signature like `{[prop: string]: Value}` but what I *want* is for `insert` to only take objects with string keys, and `Value` values.

How can I restrict `insert` in this way?

Comment: Not related: you can simplify `Value` to `type Value = string | number | bigint | boolean | null | Value[];`

Comment: @AlekseyL. Is that actually equivalent though? Isn't it recursive? i.e. will allow `[["foo"]]`?

Comment: Yes, it is recursive and will allow `[["foo"]]`. This is allowed since Typescript 3.7 https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/33050

Comment: @AlekseyL. Yeah.. it's a nice feature, but not what I wanted here :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should try this:

```js
type SingleValue =  string | number | bigint | boolean | null 
type Value = SingleValue | SingleValue[]


function insert<T extends Record<keyof T,Value>>(x: T) {

}

interface User {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

insert<User>({  // <-- no error anymore
  id: 1,
  name: 'mpen',
})
```

Explanation:

The `Record` type expects distinct key type which you can specify as a union type of keys. However, if you specify a data type like `string`, then input type must have index signature.

Comment: But this won't restrict input type to have only `string` keys https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyglgOwOYBsIDUCGKCu0C8UUAzsAE6JJQA+UCOAtgEYRk1RNxKLDtMD2-NJgTt6KFFABQoSFCy4CsSmgV528ZKux4A2gF0pRgGY4EAY2Bx+oxMVbAAPABUoEAB7AICACbEoAEoQ5vxkPo4A1hAg-MZQzgA0ahAAfCkAFO4AXPEAlFAA3kYAvkY8rMaY5tAAqvZsRUQAjDkCQhAiANxSpVJ2Do51rBmNUC1QlSj2PblAA

Comment: @AlekseyL. Yes but to add that restriction you need to define index signature in the input type. In this case ``User`` type can be defined as ``interface User { [key:string]: number | string }``. Additionally typescript allows very limited types in indexes itself (essentially ``string`` and ``number``). JavaScript by default calls ``toString`` implicitly on all indexes anyways for any given object (unless we are dealing with arrays). In example above we are using ``User`` type which has distinct keys which are already of string type. Therefore, to have additional index type check is illogical.

Comment: @SachinSingh That's not entirely true; keys can also be symbols. `type PropertyKey = string | number | symbol`

Comment: @mpen Agreed! The question is, does typescript allows that in index signature? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoQM5mQbwFDLIDaA1hAJ4BcyG5AtgEYD2ANgLrVZSgDmA3HgC+QA

Comment: @SachinSingh Ah.. yeah, no, it doesn't. Which makes sense because symbols have to have specific values.

Comment: Not true, the question is not about index signature and symbol can be used as key type https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyglgOwOYBsIDUCGKCu0C8UUAzsAE6JJQA+UCOAtgEYRk1RNxKLDtMD2-NJgTt6KFAChQkKFlwFYlNPLzt4yFdjwBtALqTDAMxwIAxsDj9RiYq2AAeACpQIAD2AQEAE2JQAShBm-GTeDgDWECD8RlBOADSqEAB8yQAUbgBccQCUUADehgC+hsEIpFBGglCEMCDMQgB0VWRpAORV-G05hjysRphm0ACqdmyFRHDe2fTMrADckkQATNmkFMiLRDqdetkCQhAiiyWStvYOo6zpE1BT2QCM8UtQq1BtDJAIbc-bu9nkPCSIo5IA

Comment: I'm not saying this is wrong, but to fulfill the requirement in the question (restriction on keys and values) you'll need something like https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyglgOwOYBsIDUCGKCu0C8UUAzsAE6JJQA+UCOAtgEYRk1RNxKLDtMD2-NJgTt6KFFABQoSFCy4CsSmgV528ZKux4A2gF0pM8NAVwAJpmAQAPABUAfFEIBrCCH4AzKHagQAHtYI5sQk5JRQAPw+um4e3nb6foEQwaFq0NG+AFx0EABurFC5CAWsANxGnjgIAMbAcPyiiMSswPYOABT+uWaW1h0AlFAA3kYAvkY8rJ6YtdAAqq1sY0QWJYwsZFJECJgMELmkFMg7UAD051AATLkCQhAiUpNSLW02S6xdq1DrUACMABoznsDrkAOQMSAIcHA8aDIA

Comment: Regarding symbol, in your example the type is inferred from value. E.g. ``type T = 'hello'; const v:T = 'world';`` won't work! Try this example & let me know if it makes sense. link in next comment.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBBCeBbGBeGBlJAjEAbAdAGYgBOAFAOTEgUCUA3AFCNTwAOApiIXEvTAHoBMALQiAfL0Q5czVpxgAVVDADejGDADaCRAF0AXHCgkAlmADmTAL5NGoSLAAeB5WnWadSQzApYAhiQUjLbMLOwcMACKKh7aANYc8Ea6Mj7QZpb8QjAAPGJKEejAZmywHCQkpEYARACCYDDmACYcTnCmFmD+UACuJJFsgf6IHFAVMPKRiL3QMFiRHKZQABYTFBnmFhQwpL5gvdIVFDUhdjk1ifA1MGsDcCsgvbjNMBwQEBxgUKb+uLjweaRfxYXCRKAgW54V7+MCA1J4ea9WAI3BNCAwMAgWB-XAgADuHFe5iaYFa7QgnW6fQGzAcc2SMXcGm0uh8fkCwVsQA

Comment: @AlekseyL. Your second solution seems intriguing. I deleted my previous comment as I did one mistake but it seems to work! Thanks for this discussion! :)

Answer (score 1):

A solution would be to change the signature of `insert` like this:

```
function insert(x: Record<string,Value>) {
  return x
}

// This is allowed
insert({
  id: 1,
  name: 'mpen',
})

/**
 * This gives the error:
 *
 * Argument of type 'number[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Record<string, Value>'.
 * Index signature is missing in type 'number[]'.
 */
insert([1, 2, 3])
```

It would restrict your input values to types like the record defined, and not let other values in, in this example, using an array which has the key a number type.

Comment: The tooling won't help me catch mistakes if I remove `<User>` from the insert.